# Trying to retrieve data from Firebase but getting null

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to retrieve data from my firebase database and print a statement in a text field but I keep getting null values. I'm using the `userid` to try and get to the child node that I want. My textfield keeps saying "Welcome null logged-in as null" [My Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/saUYR.png)

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        final String uid;
        FirebaseUser user;


        user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        uid = user.getUid();

        DatabaseReference reference = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");


         reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                fName = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("fName").getValue(String.class);
                role = dataSnapshot.child(uid).child("role").getValue(String.class);

            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

        welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
        welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + fName + "! You are logged-in as " + role);
```

Comment: Have you debugged to see exactly what's in `dataSnapshot`? Is your callback even being called?

Comment: If you are getting correct data in DataSnapshot then move this line 
welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + fName + "! You are logged-in as " + role) 
inside onDataChanged().

Comment: Most likely you're being affected by the asynchronous nature of loading data from Firebase, and your `welcomeText.setText(...)` executes before the `onDataChange` has been called. See my answer here for more details and examples: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50434836/getcontactsfromfirebase-method-return-an-empty-list/50435519#50435519

Answer (score 1):

Move the following lines to the onDataChange() callback method.

```
welcomeText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcomeText);
welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + fName + "! You are logged-in as " + role);
```

Comment: Thanks, i did this but im still getting null values

Comment: that's okay. all the best

Comment: please remember to explain WHY when you give an answer, giving an answer which works is one thing, but then others don't learn from it, friendly tip :)

Answer (score 1):

You should pass your `userid` as child to get data for only the logged in user. Currently you loop through all the users which gives you wrong data at the end.
Try like below:

```
DatabaseReference reference = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User").child(uid);
```

instead of

```
DatabaseReference reference = 
      FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User");
```

Beside this, Currently you are setting the initial value of `fName` and `role` which is null and never update the value with your user detail which you get inside `onDataChange`. So, update your `TextView` inside `onDataChange`.

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    fName = dataSnapshot.child("fName").getValue(String.class);
    role = dataSnapshot.child("role").getValue(String.class);

    welcomeText.setText("Welcome " + fName + "! You are logged-in as " + role);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i did this but im still getting null values

Comment: How did you fix this?